# URL from string is null

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a string from a URL but the URL is null. The string does certainly contain something but the URL is still null.

Here is where I create the URL:

```
NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
NSString *stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Here is the string before being turned into a URL: %@", stringForURL);
NSURL *finalURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
finalURL = details.finalURL;

NSLog(@"Here is the final URL: %@", finalURL);
```

Comment: After initializing `finalURL` using `initWithString:[stringForURL...`, why are you then overwriting the just-initialized value by setting `finalURL` equal to `details.finalURL`?

Comment: So I am creating a URL per cell, which creates a corresponding URL to each image in the tableView. The finalURL is then passed to the view controller that gets called when the cell is selected and is then used in that view controller.

Comment: You didn't really answer Anna's question. The first 4 lines you posted won't do anything, since you then redefine finalURL to be equal to details.finalURL. What is details.finalURL? Where does that come from?

Comment: Yes, I now see my error. The ='s was going the wrong way. @rdelmar

Comment: @Matthew, i have updated your answer please follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your final url code to below:-

```
  Nstring *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
   [stringForURL 
 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Hey, this works great and the url is now appearing. The only problem is that I am using a UITableView and when a row is selected, it takes you to the place you can watch the video but the video is not being retrieved from coredata correctly, it just shows the newest video in ever cell. Do you have any idea how I could make this work. (I know this is different from the question but I thought I might as well ask)

Comment: Not much sure. But the problem might be in your uitableview data source merhod cellForRowAtindex. Because as we know it is use for populating the data. Please check that one.